# Incorrect noun form

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I always use these kinds of sentences when I refer to use or have a "custom" object.

> I have a custom bicycle
>
> you have to implement a custom solution

since a while ago I'm using grammarly (chrome plug-in), and I got errors referring to "incorrect noun form", and I have no idea how to correct the sentence grammatically.

any explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: It probably wants you to say _customised_ or _customized_.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on the premise that ELU is here to explain shortcomings in (relatively dumb) software-based grammar checkers.

Comment: I think that's unfair FumbleFingers. Humans programmed those grammar-checkers. Besides, the limitations of computers parsing language illustrates interesting facets of the language. And the question certainly doesn't suggest that ELU is here just to explain software shortcomings.

Comment: @RustyTuba - at best it is a General Reference question. Any good dictionary will explain the use of 'custom' as an adjective.

Comment: That's true. But this site wouldn't exist if Grammarly could get it right every time.

Comment: @RustyTuba- do not see any logic in your 'existence' theory.

Comment: "existence theory"? I mean that a question about what Grammarly finds acceptable is perfectly fine for this site. Everyone here is arguing about English language and usage, and if there were no argument, then we would be able to produce perfect software.

Comment: I don't understand why the downvote, this is a very genuine doubt, common question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Grammarly bills itself as the "World's Best Grammar Checker," it has limitations. In fact, it must play the law of percentages, and - like many grammar checkers - fails to happily marry semantics and syntax.

What I mean is that "custom" is, in this case, identified as a noun. Grammarly doesn't like to see "custom" plus another noun, despite the fact that many dictionaries do in fact list "custom" as an adjective, with common examples being "custom suit" or "custom cabinets." Try those expressions (undeniably common ones) in Grammarly and see what happens. They will be flagged as noun problems.

Grammarly wants the adjective "customized." However, with fabricated objects we typically use "custom" rather than "customized," just as in your first example. However, some people may find "custom solution" a bit awkward, because with solutions and services and non-fabricated items it may be more common to use "customized."

Note that Grammarly doesn't recognize *all* noun + noun combinations as incorrect. For example, type "I have a grammar problem" into Grammarly and it will pass.

p.s. what the heck word form is "Grammarly" anyways?

Comment: "Grammarly" is an adnoun.  Duh!